# Looking for an algorithm

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, combinations, recursive-algorithms

I have a very long "list" of numbers ( maybe thousands ) which may be grouped, by sum into "n" groups. The number of groups and values are given. For example:

- List of numbers: [1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8.5, 10]
- Groups:[3, 15, 21.5]

I need to find a summary of which numbers in the "list" will crate given "groups".

- 3 = 1+2
- 15 = 5+10
- 21.5 = 6+7+8.5

Ideas?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is basically the subset-sum-problem , which is NP-complete. Maybe there are efficient algorithms working well in practical instances.

Comment: subset-sum talking about finding a solution for one target only, not to list of targets

Comment: Are the numbers from the given list and the groups such that the solution exists and it's unique?

Comment: @jjagmath Yes, it is

Comment: @DoktopAibolit That means that your problem is harder than subset-sum, so at least as hard as NP complete. I think this question would be better suited at SO or the computer science stack exchange.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the problem via integer linear programming as follows.  Let binary decision variable $x_{i,g}$ indicate whether item $i$ (with value $v_i$) appears in group $g$.  Let $s_g$ be the target sum for group $g$.  The problem is to find a feasible solution to the linear constraints
\begin{align}
\sum_g x_{i,g} &= 1 &&\text{for all $i$} \\
\sum_i v_i x_{i,g} &= s_g &&\text{for all $g$}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a variation of [The Subset Sum Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem#Exponential_time_algorithms) Given a list of numbers, does some subset's sum equal 0? The complexity remains the same if the target isn't zero.

A brute force algorithm is loop through the desired targets generating subsets, then add each subset's terms. There are $2^N-1$ possible subsets if you ignore the empty set. You can generate the subsets by generating the first $2^N-1$ binary numbers, and have a routine that can convert the number into its corresponding sum. $1$ means include, $0$ means exclude.

You probably don't want to use this method for 1000 data points. That article has some alternatives.